# Domain driven design (how to) + implementation (java)

Tags: java, jpa, domain-driven-design

I'm reading a lot about DDD in couple of last days and I'm not clear about some things agains my test design.

I have a scenario where I have **Company** which have two **Address**es (billing and shipping). This addresses belongs only to this company so it isn't needed to share it between many companies. Similar to this I have **User** who has many **Role**s. Again this roles belongs only to this user (Role is enum). How should I model this in DDD? 
Company should have primary address and secondary address as element (valued object)? Are they both valued objects or are they entities? Also what with roles in user entity? Is here role valued object or is it entity (what is better)?

If I want to implement this using java (using JPA for example) what would be the final result? Should I create elements (address and role) as set of valued objects so they will be in separate table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I believe that you are mixing some concepts. DDD is all about designing your application to encapsulate it'd domain in objects and behavior. It has nothing to do with data modeling (the database layer of the application).

For one application, an Address can be a Value Object but for others it can be an Entity. It depends of the domain and the concepts being encapsulated in your application. It's the same with the Role.

I know that this isn't the type of answer you want. But I think that is important to clarify those concepts to avoid future mistakes. To give you a answer with a suggestion of modeling it would need more input about your system and the mapped use cases.

As a suggestion, I believe that you already read the Domain Driven Design book, by Eric Evans. Anyway this is a great book!

Hope it helps! :)

Edit 1:

Ok. I'll assume that you want your Company to be an aggregate for the Addresses. From a DDD point of view it doesn't matter if they are in a single table or not. What is important is to use the concept of Aggregates and don't let any direct access to the Address but through the Company. You can achieve this correctly using your access methods.

For the User and Role I wouldn't code the User as an aggregator for Role.

One point of attention: I read the links that you said and I noticed that it's code examples don't use JPA or anything alike. It recommends you to refer to other aggregation by id and not by object reference. But this technic is not recommended when working with JPA.

Comment: i was thinking more about something like [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_1.pdf) [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_2.pdf) and [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_3.pdf) . Here author is telling about design and providing some code. So for me it would be helpful if someone can tell me his opinion from his point of view. And I would like to know how developers are resolving this issues.

Comment: I don't think I can give some code example without knowing more of the domain you are modeling. I edited my answer with some personal thoughts. Hope it helps!